# Can you use firebase-admin.firebase.Timestamp instead of FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

For generating server side timestamps in Google Cloud functions it seems like the documentation tends to point to using `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

But there is also an option to use `import {Timestamp} from "firebase-admin/firestore"` which has a function `Timestamp.now()`.  Seems a much easier way to get at the current time on the server than using  `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. Do you end up with the same time either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the timestamp on the server that executes the Cloud Function will be exactly the same as the time when the data is written to the database.

The two operations happen on different machines, so even if the clocks were complete in sync, there's time that passes between executing the operations on those different machines. When the machines are in different zones/regions, that time difference may well be non-trivial.

This level of difference may of course not be important for your application, but that's something only you can determine. I recommend measuring the difference between the two values in your project before deciding.

Comment: Very helpful. As it turns out I"m more concerned with when a cloud function runs, (which measures when a user requests some data) then when the db.write of the inquiry happens..  I am curious though, when you have a statement like model.timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() (which is not tied a db write), is that going to yield a timestamp that is derived from some other machine?

Comment: The `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is a so-called sentinel (really just some well-known constant) that the client sends, and that the database server then interprets and replaces with the actual timestamp.

Comment: Right, so If i tried to use the value of foo=admin.firestoreFieldValue.serverTimestamp() before it was written to the database, would it return this sentinel value instead of the time?

Comment: Yup, exactly. ---

Answer (score 1):

Firestore timestamps are generated when the document is modified/created on the database server. Other timestamps can be used for logic, but those are independent of Firestore timestamps.

```
ref.set({
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```